# form inside table

Tags: forms

Why is this wrong?

```
<table>
  <form>
    <tr><td>something something</td/>
  </form>
</table>
```

I'm talking about position of form tags inside table tags.

Comment: You're missing a close `</tr> tag on your post. Can you please fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html):

```
<!ELEMENT TABLE - -
     (CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)>
<!ELEMENT CAPTION  - - (%inline;)*     -- table caption -->
<!ELEMENT THEAD    - O (TR)+           -- table header -->
<!ELEMENT TFOOT    - O (TR)+           -- table footer -->
<!ELEMENT TBODY    O O (TR)+           -- table body -->
<!ELEMENT COLGROUP - O (COL)*          -- table column group -->
<!ELEMENT COL      - O EMPTY           -- table column -->
<!ELEMENT TR       - O (TH|TD)+        -- table row -->
<!ELEMENT (TH|TD)  - O (%flow;)*       -- table header cell, table data cell-->
```

These are the only elements you can have inside a `table` element (in HTML 4 in this case, but you check the same kind of document for other versions, and it's not changed much).

---

On the other hand, a `form` element can contain any other block-level element (except other forms):

```
<!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->
```

And the `td` element can contain any "flow" element (as seen in the first code block), and "flow" include block level elements:

```
<!ENTITY % flow "%block; | %inline;">
```

So you can put your `<form>` tags either around the entire table or inside one table cell.

Answer (score 2):

Only the elements CAPTION, COL, COLGROUP, THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY are allowed as child elements of the TABLE element. See [The TABLE element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE) in the HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can only put `<form>` tags inside `<td>` or outside `<table>`, according to the standards.